# Simple Bash regular expression match missing char (OS X)

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I am matching a regular expression in bash on OS X 10.11:

```
$ msg='[4]  the message'
$  [[ $msg =~ (.+)\t(.+) ]]
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
[4]
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
he message
```

Between the `']'` and the `'t'` of `$msg` is a tab character. There is no tab in either `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` or `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`. Where did the `'t'` go?

Comment: I think you'll find there's *is* a tab in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` (for the reason explained in @xhienne's answer i.e. `$msg` is getting split on the literal `t`) - but the unquoted variable is subject to word splitting by the shell; you'd have seen it if you'd done `echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`

Comment: Try it. I get nothing following the ]. Which is what confused me.

Comment: `msg='[4]  the message' ; [[ $msg =~ (.+)\t(.+) ]] ; echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" | od -tx1` ==> `0000000 5b 34 5d 09 0a` (`5d` is the closing `]`, and `09` is the tab)

Answer (score 5):

The 't' is between the two sub-regex: `\t`, which isn't interpreted as a tabulation but as `t`. A tabulation would be `$'\t'`.

Try this instead:

```
$ msg=$'[4]\tthe message'
$ [[ "$msg" =~ (.+)$'\t'(.+) ]]
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
[4]
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
the message
```